can't update (ubuntu 24.04)
sudo apt update gives me the following error:
Hit:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble InRelease
Hit:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-security InRelease               
Hit:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble InRelease                      
Err:4 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos.vscode stable InRelease             
  403  Forbidden [IP: 13.107.246.40 443]
Hit:5 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/gns3/ppa/ubuntu noble InRelease
Hit:6 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/jentiger-moratai/mediatools/ubuntu noble InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
E: Failed to fetch https://packages.microsoft.com/repos.vscode/dists/stable/InRelease  403  Forbidden [IP: 13.107.246.40 443]
E: The repository 'https://packages.microsoft.com/repos.vscode stable InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.

I've tried
$ wget -qO- https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | gpg --dearmor > packages.microsoft.gpg
$ sudo install -D -o root -g root -m 644 packages.microsoft.gpg /etc/apt/keyrings/packages.microsoft.gpg rm -f packages.microsoft.gpg

but it says -- 'f' is an invalid option.
I also tried
$ sudo apt-get clean
$ sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
$ sudo apt-get update

which got to Get:69 and then gave me the same error as before.
This started when I tried to install VirtualBox yesterday. I don't if I did something to cause it, or if it was already going to do that anyway. I'm still very new to Linux. Kinda wish I had downloaded a slightly older version of Ubuntu, I heard that having the newest version causes you to be more likely to run into compatibility issues.

Welcome to AskUbuntu. This does not appear to be a compatibility issue, but a malformed command. For the action with the 'f' is an invalid option error, you have an rm command alongside an apt install. If you are new to Linux, it would be better to perform each command individually so that you can become more familiar with their usage and also the sorts of errors each might return.

See answer at this site (same error - Release no longer signed)  which seemed to be (in their case) caused by an outage. https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/120383

This question is similar to: Dell Canonical repository is not signed (GPG error) and How to fix: "Error dependency is not satisfiable"?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
